# C execution Time

Tags: c, time, timer, execution

I have a problem when I want to check my execution time with time.h in C. Namely; I added a timer for calculation of execution time when a search is started. However, the timer is starting when I select a number of variables.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int selection = 0;
    printf(" 1. Calculate Execution Time Depends on Variables. \n 2. Calculate Variable Numbers Depends on Time Execution.\n  What You want to do ? \n Selection :  ");
    scanf_s("%d", &selection);

    if (selection==1)
    {   
        int numberselection = 0;
        int number_Elements = 0;

        printf(" Please Select the Number of Elements. \n 1. 500.000    2. 1.000.000    3. 2.000.000    4. 3.000.000    5. 100.000.000 \n Selection : ");
        scanf_s("%d", &numberselection);

        if (numberselection==1)
        {
            number_Elements = 500000;
        }
        if (numberselection == 2)
        {
            number_Elements = 1000000;

        }
        if (numberselection == 3)
        {
            number_Elements = 2000000;

        }
        if (numberselection == 4)
        {
            number_Elements = 3000000;

        }
        if (numberselection == 5)
        {
            number_Elements = 100000000;

        }

        int i = 0;

        int *NumberList = malloc(number_Elements * sizeof(int));

        NumberList[number_Elements];

        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        for (i = 0; i < number_Elements; i++)
        {
            double random = rand() % 99999 + 99999999;


            NumberList[i] = random;
        }

        double number_Search;

        printf("\n Please Enter Number To Search : ");
        scanf_s("%d", &number_Search);



        Algorithm(number_Elements, NumberList, number_Search);





    }





    return 0;


}

 int Algorithm(int G_Number_Elements , int G_NumberList[] , int G_Number_Search)
{
    int k = 0;

    double time_taken = 0;


    clock_t t = 0;
    for ( k = 0; k < G_Number_Elements; k++) // NUMBER TO TIME
    {
        if (G_NumberList[k] == G_Number_Search)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n Not Found...");
            break;
        }


    }

    t = clock() - t;
    time_taken = ((double)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("\n Exacution Time Depends %d Variables = %f  ms.\n", G_Number_Elements, time_taken);

    return 0;
}
```

The time I wait for the console is added when I get the timer value. I have a two scenario;

[Pictures of Scenarios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G43w.png)

My question is that, How can I eliminate the waiting time from the timer?

Comment: It could be operating system specific, since there are several notions of time. If you are on Linux, read carefully [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). Otherwise, consider using [date & time utilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono) in C, or [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) in C++. Notice that C and C++ are *different* programming languages.

Comment: do you place clock_t t = 0; as start time point? if yes it should be clock_t t = clock();

Comment: BTW, `clock` is rumored to be buggy on Windows (it measures some kind of "real elapsed time" and it should measure "cpu time").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `clock()` counts all clock ticks your program uses.
You probably want to initialize `t` to the current value of `clock()` like this

```
clock_t t = clock();
```

That way you take the amount of time spent on selecting your input out of the time calculation.

Additinal information taken from the [C reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/) on `clock()`

> To calculate the actual processing time of a program, the value returned by clock shall be compared to a value returned by a previous call to the same function.

Comment: I changed that like :    clock_t t = clock();
                                      # for loops. 
                                       t =  clock() - t;
                                       time_taken = ((double)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

but its show 0 ms.

Comment: What value does clock() return? Also t / CLOCKS_PER_SEC calculates the execution time in seconds, not milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem by the help of @Korrat !

Last state of codes :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{

    int selection = 0;
    printf(" 1. Calculate Execution Time Depends on Variables. \n 2. Calculate Variable Numbers Depends on Time Execution.\n \n What You Want to Do ? \n Selection :  ");
    scanf_s("%d", &selection);

    if (selection == 1)
    {
        int numberselection = 0;
        int number_Elements = 0;

        printf(" Please Select the Number of Elements. \n 1. 500.000    2. 1.000.000    3. 2.000.000    4. 3.000.000    5. 100.000.000 \n Selection : ");
        scanf_s("%d", &numberselection);

        if (numberselection == 1)
        {
            number_Elements = 500000;
        }
        if (numberselection == 2)
        {
            number_Elements = 1000000;

        }
        if (numberselection == 3)
        {
            number_Elements = 2000000;

        }
        if (numberselection == 4)
        {
            number_Elements = 3000000;

        }
        if (numberselection == 5)
        {
            number_Elements = 100000000;

        }


        int i = 0;

        int *NumberList = malloc(number_Elements * sizeof(int));

        NumberList[number_Elements];

        srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
        for (i = 0; i < number_Elements; i++)
        {
            double random = rand() % 99999 + 99999999;


            NumberList[i] = random;
        }

        double number_Search;

        printf("\n Please Enter Number To Search : ");
        scanf_s("%d", &number_Search);

        int k = 0;

        clock_t begin = clock();

        for (k = 0; k <= number_Elements; k++) // NUMBER TO TIME
        {
            if (NumberList[k] == number_Search)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (k == number_Elements)
            {
                printf("Your Number Not Found in List ! \n");

            }



        }

        clock_t end = clock();
        float time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        printf("\n Exacution Time Depends %d Variables = %f  Second !. \n", number_Elements, time_spent);


    }





    return 0;
}
```